# Swing keybinding to control an animated car

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, animation

In my textbook there is no mention of keybindings and it encourages the use of keylistener so there isn't any example code using keybindings for its problems. I was wondering if this is sorta close to how I'm supposed to use them.

I tried to let one Action object handle all the keybinds and use the event info to determine the action taken (like how KeyListener processes a KeyEvent and we can get information from it), but I was unable to find a way to obtain additional information... getActionCommand() didn't work either since it kept returning null for non-ascii keys. The only solution that I could think of was using separate Action instances to process each key.

Here's the [exercise](http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-457hfjdol7/Introduction-to-Java-Programming-660.html):

> (Racing car) Write a Java program that simulates car racing, as shown in 
>   Figure 16.23a. The car moves from left to right. When it hits the right end, it
>   restarts from the left and continues the same process. You can use a timer to
>   control animation. Redraw the car with a new base coordinates (x, y), as
>   shown in Figure 16.23b. Also let the user pause/resume the animation with a
>   button press/release and increase/decrease the car speed by pressing the UP
>   and DOWN arrow keys.

My code attempt:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RacingCar extends JFrame {
public RacingCar() {
    add(new CarPanel());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new RacingCar();
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class CarPanel extends JPanel {
    private int baseX = 0;
    private int baseY = 0;
    private boolean reverse = false;
    private int delay = 10;     // Initial delay
    private Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Change the base alignment depending the direction of car

            if (!reverse) {
                baseX++;
            }
            else {
                baseX--;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });


    public CarPanel() {
        //Add keybinds for UP and DOWN keys as well as the 'P' key to pause/resume
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "speedUp");
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "slowDown");
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("P"), "pause");
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released P"), "resume");


        //Define actions for each key
        getActionMap().put("speedUp", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (delay > 0) {
                    delay -= 1;
                    timer.setDelay(delay);
                }
            }
        });
        getActionMap().put("slowDown", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delay += 1;
                timer.setDelay(delay);
            }
        });
        getActionMap().put("pause", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        });
        getActionMap().put("resume", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        timer.start();

    }

    //Method for painting the car at the given base
    private void drawCar(Graphics g) {
        //Check if car is at an end
        if (!reverse && baseX == getWidth() - 50)
            reverse = true;
        else if (baseX == 0)
            reverse = false;

        //Draw top of car
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillPolygon(new int[]{baseX + 10, baseX + 20, baseX + 30, baseX + 40},
          new int[]{baseY - 20, baseY - 30, baseY - 30, baseY - 20}, 4);

        //Draw body of car
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(baseX, baseY - 20, 50, 10);

        //Draw wheels
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(baseX + 10, baseY - 10, 10, 10);
        g.fillOval(baseX + 30, baseY - 10, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Initialize baseY coordinates
        if (baseY == 0)
            baseY = getHeight();

        drawCar(g);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `My code attempt` Does it work as intended?